# Can Sphinx emit the 'module contents' first and the 'submodules' last?

Tags: python-sphinx

I typically put the high-level documentation for a Python package into the docstring of its `__init__.py` file.  This makes sense to me, given that the `__init__.py` file represents the package's interface with the outside world.  (And, really, where else would you put it?)

So, I was really quite surprised when I fired up Sphinx for the first time and saw this content buried near the very end of the package documentation, after the content for all of the submodules.

This seems backward to me.  The very first thing the user *will* see when he visits the page for a package is the documentation of the submodule that just happens to come first alphabetically, and the thing he *should* see first is right near the bottom.

I wonder if there is a way to fix this, to make the stuff inside of `__init__.py` come out first, before all of the stuff in the submodules.  And if I am just going about this in the wrong way, I want to know that.  Thanks!

Comment: Looks like others have felt my pain.  This option may already exist, or soon exist: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/sphinx-users/module$20contents/sphinx-users/Bm4w7OQcWYM/C-EKpZZpSbEJ

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Updated Answer (thank you, Donal Fellows):**

https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-apidoc.html#cmdoption-sphinx-apidoc-M

**Original Answer:**

Yes, there is an option to do this, it's just not documented [here](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/man/sphinx-apidoc.html).  Inside my copy of `Sphinx-1.3.3/sphinx/apidoc.py` I found this:

```
parser.add_option('-M', '--module-first', action='store_true',
                  dest='modulefirst',
                  help='Put module documentation before submodule '
                  'documentation')
```

I tried it and it works like a charm.

Comment: It's documented here: http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/invocation.html#cmdoption-sphinx-apidoc-M

Comment: Thanks for that.  Google took me [here](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/man/sphinx-apidoc.html), which does not mention the option.

Comment: The option (version 3.5.1) is now mentioned [here](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-apidoc.html#cmdoption-sphinx-apidoc-M).

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to add this option in the `conf.py` file.

Search in `conf.py` for the line where the string containing the `sphinx-apidoc` command is (located in a try section) and add the `"--module-first"` option.

The new line will look like this:

`cmd_line_template = "sphinx-apidoc --module-first -f -o {outputdir} {moduledir}"`

Answer (score 0):

Hadn't used Sphinx in a while, but it does seem like they've done a good job updating it.  In the past, I had to manually specify the classes since I didn't like how autodoc generated the methods/functions.  Now it does seem like you can order them:

```
.. autoclass:: YourClass
   :members: __init__, __getitem__
```

http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html